# MVVMCross Conference Example: How to click on item

Tags: mvvmcross

In the example, the item detail is displayed when the user clicks the session text.
How do you open the item detail when user clicks on the item in the list view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are talking about this sample: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/master/Sample%20-%20CirriousConference/Cirrious.Conference.UI.Droid/Resources/Layout/Page_SessionList.axml

Note this is a few years old now and the syntax in v3 is far simpler.

You can now use ItemClick on the list's bind as follows (this is for android):-

```
local:MvxBind="ItemsSource GroupedList; ItemClick SessionSelectedCommand"
```

Then inside your session list viewmodel have a ICommand property as follows:-

```
ICommand SessionSelectedCommand 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        return new MvxCommand<Session>(DoSessionSelected);
    }
}
```

Finally add a method DosessionSelected which would then do the navigation.

```
private void DoSessionSelected(Session selectedSession)
{
   //Do the navigation here.
}
```

Comment: I figured the source codes are from different versions, thus making things a bit difficult for a newbie like me. Thanks, I got it to work with your help.

Comment: The n+1 videos are all based on the new stuff - I highly recommend using them to skill up quickly on the v3 stuff.